# Female hacker who sees how a lot of people die; possibly called "Beautiful Net"

Tags: story-identification, books, novel, artificial-intelligence

I remember I once read a book (around 2008) about this hacker girl who mysteriously sees how a lot of people die in strange circumstances. The story takes place in a very near future (I hope), when you can be connected to the internet at any time without equipment, cause you have a screen of some kind in your eye (kind of like Google's newest invention).  You use your hand to control the device.

She ask for the help of one friend that she only knows on the network, and not in real life. At the end of the novel, turns out this friend is a piece of software (AI).

I remember the name was "Beautiful net" but I cannot find it anywhere online...

**More information**

I've just remember. The main object of the AI software that helped the girl to delete the virus killing people was a chat-software designed to talk to people but to learn and be more natural.

**More Information yet**

The girl went to a congress of some sort, and as soon as she approach the place where it will be, she is logged off of the network (she does not need any equipment, cause all is built-in his brain) and to get connected to the congress network she needs the information that will be given once she is there.

There she knows this guy who ultimately turns to be the one who created the virus killing people.

Comment: Hi!  I edited your question to make it a little more readable.  If I changed too much you can ignore the edit.  Some more information that might be helpful- when did you read this book and what language was it in?  Was it new when you read it?  Did it seem like it was meant for adults, or for children?  Good luck!

Comment: I read it in 2008 (around). It was kind of new (like one year maybe). For all audience.

Thanks for the edition!

Comment: @Abraham Was there a virus that was destroying the connection, and the people that were connecting to it?

Comment: @Jersey Yeap, it was. :)

Comment: @Abraham ... I've been looking for this same story, and gave up a while ago! I'm not a hundred percent that the name was 'Beautiful Net', but Net was in the title. It was more cyberpunk, but if I remember correctly the virus was in her somehow.

Comment: @Jersey, No. I remember they used some kind of Augmented Reality to browse the web, and they can connect only in the areas designated. She had a scooter also hehe. And her only friend at the end turns out to be the AI software helping the world against the ones trying to control it (kind of...)

Comment: Hey @Jersey, I've added more data I've just remember :)

Comment: This seems slightly similar to Otherland by Tad Williams.

Comment: Thanks @Aurora... but it is not the same.

Comment: Is there any possibility that this could be *Ganesa.net*? It would seem too old, but it has an evil AI, the word net in the title, a female hacker, etc....

Comment: Thank you @Jonah! Unfortunately it is not :( but seems nice to read though

Answer (score 5):

Could it be *WWW: Wake* by Robert J. Sawyer, the first book of the WWW Trilogy?

It involves a blind girl who gets a retinal implant that allows her to see the structure of the Internet; she eventually contacts an AI.

[Here is a full synopsis](http://www.sfwriter.com/syw1.htm).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer... I gave it a point cause it added one more "must-read" to my list... unfortunately, it is not the one I'm looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This might possibly be Neal Stephenson's Snow Crash. The main protagonists in that book are a pizza delivery guy and a strong female character. It's a seminal cyberpunk novel.

The title of the book refers to a computer virus which is able to infect 'Internet' users themselves.

There is also an element of the chat software which the protagonist had worked on in a previous job as a programmer/hacker.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_Crash

Comment: While Snow Crash has some similarities, there are enough points of difference to rule it out. People don't have implants to be on the 'net, they use (rather bulky) equipment. And there's no friend-who-turns-out-to-be-an-AI.

Comment: Fair enough. Snow Crash is definitely worth reading though ;)

Comment: Even worth reading twice. :)

Comment: If not more than that